# Is there any way to disable image downloads when scraping data using PHP cURL?

Tags: php, curl

I just need text data. I can't find the answer to it anywhere.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, cURL will not download the images, but only the HTML text. You might have image tags in there, but that doesn't make PHP download the appropriate images.

Comment: Got it. Thanks. It's because I'm dispalying the content of the cURL, which is html, that prompts the browser to download images.

Comment: you are right. The only way he would be downloading the images I guess would be if he had some kind of cURL spider script.

Answer (score -1):

I am not familiar with cURL but you can use get filecontents

```
<?php
$homepage = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/');
echo $homepage;
?>
```